# Robolectric java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.android.app.R contains final fields

Tags: junit, robolectric

I am testing a legacy app with resources distributed across 3 packages.
So I extended RobolectricTestRunner and modified resource path as below.

```
public class DialerRobolectricTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    @Override
    protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {

     return new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(manifestPath), 
     Fs.fileFromPath(resDir), Fs.fileFromPath(assetsDir)) {

       @Override
       public List<ResourcePath> getIncludedResourcePaths() {
           List<ResourcePath> paths = super.getIncludedResourcePaths();

           paths.add(new ResourcePath(getRClass(),Fs.fileFromPath("../pkg1/res/"), getAssetsDirectory()));
           paths.add(new ResourcePath(getRClass(), Fs.fileFromPath("../pkg2/res/"), getAssetsDirectory()));
           paths.add(new ResourcePath(getRClass(), Fs.fileFromPath("../pkg2/res/"), getAssetsDirectory()));
           return paths;
       }
    }
}
```

I see below exception while testing android app with Robolectric

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.android.app.R contains final fields, these will be inlined by the compiler and cannot be remapped.
```

Robolectric : 3.3.2, 
sdk : 23

Comment: You have relative paths. The working dir for Robolectric is module dir, so it should probably be like "src/pkg1/..."

Comment: These packages are outside my source. Like myapp/src/pkg , app1/src/pkg1/ , app2/src/pkg2 . It is legacy code and cant do much. But i dont see this issue with robolectric 3.1.1 where ResourcePath construction is different.

Comment: Hi Eugen, Looks like this is intentional.
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/commit/6a7bdc7a1b1fbe38142995bde5f05023b8ab86ad                                                                           would you have any suggestion about tackling this ?

Comment: How about to copy them in the proper place?

Comment: I had given try already, It works, though bit clumsy.